# React change class of component without using state

Tags: reactjs

How can I change the className or style of a div without using state or any third party libraries? Lets say I click on a button, and I need to change the background color of a div how can I do that?

```
<Affix onChange={() => change css or class} offsetTop={60}>
<div>...</div> // Change css of this div
</Affix>
```

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: why not using state?

Comment: This is not the proper way to do it in React, BUT you can still use javascript and the `document`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information

Comment: I dont want the app to re render everytime the navbar is activated @assembler

Comment: @Striped thats not the proper way to do that in react

Comment: you can use a memo

Comment: the proper way to do that in react is using state

Comment: @assembler how would it be done using useMemo?

Comment: if you don't want to use state then why use react you can do that with javascript main point is react work good with state and it handle it well so why not use state

Comment: The best way to change class is state

Comment: @Chandan the reason is because I am dealing with a large amount of data on the page and if the user keeps activating and deactivating the navbar the page will re render hundreds of times

Comment: you can move navbar to another component with it state than you can change state and will not effect other components is it not possible to move navbar to another component

Comment: @Chandan Thank you this worked!

Comment: @hernandeΩ check te documentatio for using memos, you can memoize a component or a function... that will reduce the number of renders

Answer (score 2):

You can change any attribute or property of a Component (Element) in React by using basic javascript functions.

```
onClick={(e) => {
    e.currentTarget.setAttribute("src", newUrl);
}
```

Will change an image the moment you click on it, without using Ref or State.
event.currentTarget will give you the reference to the component that fired that particular React.MouseEventHandler event, and with the Element's reference, you can manipulate it at will.

This is particularly useful when you need to change an attribute in a component in a map loop without needing to keep track of it.

Edit:
A friend of mine just gave me a better one for classes in specific:

```
e.currentTarget.classList.add('my_custom_klass')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either do it manually using state:

```
const [myClass, setMyClass] = useState('bgColor-white');

return (
  <Affix onChange={() => setMyClass('bgColor-black')} offsetTop={60}>
    <div className={myClass}>...</div> // Change css of this div
  </Affix>
)
```

Or you can use a library that handles dynamic styling. I use and recommend [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)